# How would I be able to add pin in Bing Maps api with this code?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, bing-maps

How would I be able to add pin in Bing Maps api with this code:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  attributeBindings: ['style'],
  classNames: ['bing-map'],
  bingKey: "bing-key",
  width: '45%',
  height: '100%',
  latitude: 0,
  longitude: 0,
  zoom: 0,
  mapTypeId: 'r', // r:road, a:aerial

  init: function(){
    this._super();
    if (!this.get('bingKey')){
      throw('Missing bingKey');
    }
    this.api = Microsoft.Maps;
    this.map = null;
  },

  style: function(){
    return "position: relative; width: %@px; height: %@px".fmt(
      this.get('width'),
      this.get('height')
    );
  }.property('width', 'height'),

  center: function(){
    var latitude  = parseFloat(this.get('latitude'));
    var longitude = parseFloat(this.get('longitude'));
    longitude = this.api.Location.normalizeLongitude(longitude);

    return new this.api.Location(latitude, longitude);
  }.property('latitude', 'longitude'),

  mapOptions: function(){
    return {
      center:      this.get('center'),
      zoom:        parseInt(this.get('zoom'),10),
      mapTypeId:   this.get('mapTypeId')
    };
  }.property('center','zoom','mapTypeId'),

  createMap: function(){
    var el = this.$()[0];
    var options = this.get('mapOptions');
    options.credentials = this.get('bingKey');
    this.map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(el, options);
  }.on('didInsertElement'),

    removeMap: function(){
      this.map.dispose();
    }.on('willDestroyElement'),


});
```

I am using ember-cli and trying to set pins on the map depending on the item that is chosen inside the template table, but I am unable to get how to set a pin on the map implemented in this code (which I need). The info in the Microsoft Bing Map api website is not helping.

Anyone know how to achieve this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about Ember or your code. But if you can figure out where in your code you have the coordinates for the location you want to show as a pin you can easily create a pin like this:

```
var loc = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(latitude, longitude);
var pushpin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(loc); 
map.entities.push(pushpin);
```